# How to construct struct based on json

Tags: ios, json, swift4

I have list Json result based on that I created struct but while parsing getting an error typeMismatch. I am not able to find what's wrong going while create structs in code

I have created struct based on json which is not working for me

```
["status": "1",
"error": false,
"data": [
    {
        "order_id": "11",
        "order_unique_id": "ORDR-1001",
        "store_name": "24X7",
        "otp_store": "781103",
        "product": [
            "Product One",
            "Product Two"
        ],
        "qty": [
            "1",
            "3"
        ],
        "user_details": {
            "name": "test",
            "number": "98145314586",
            "landmark": "test",
            "area": "Bow East",
            "pincode": "E3 9EG",
            "place": "Home"
        },
        "status": "2",
        "date": "2018-12-13",
        "time": "14:37:57"
    }]


struct RunnerStatus: Decodable {
var status: String
var error: Bool
var data: [Runner]
}

struct Runner: Decodable {
var order_id: String
var order_unique_id: String
var store_name: String
var otp_store: String
var product: [Product]
var qty: [Quantity]
var user_details: [UserDetails]
var status: String
var date: String
var time: String
}

struct Product: Decodable {
var ProductName: String
}

struct Quantity: Decodable {
var qty: String
}

struct UserDetails: Decodable {
var name: String
var number: String
var landmark: String
var area: String
var pincode: String
var place: String
}
```

all struct should bind with there associated value/Data

Comment: "an error typeMismatch.": Show us the full error. That way we can help you understand it (so you can fix yourself similar issues), faster get the issue, etc.

Comment: convert your json to struct codable use this link: http://www.json4swift.com/

Comment: @Larme error was     rror serializing json: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))

Comment: This can't be the real error. The type for `data` is correct. You should get errors about `product` and `qty`.

Comment: @vadian yeah but can you point out the region because I don't know why it's happen

Comment: Both types of `product` and `qty` are string **array**s (`[String]`). A custom struct is always representing a **dictionary**.

Comment: @vadian got it thanks for response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you structure should be as follows:

```
// 1
struct RootClass : Codable {

    let data : [RunnerData]?
    let error : Bool?
    let status : String?
}

// 2
struct RunnerData : Codable {

    let date : String?
    let orderId : String?
    let orderUniqueId : String?
    let otpStore : String?
    let product : [String]?
    let qty : [String]?
    let status : String?
    let storeName : String?
    let time : String?
    let userDetails : UserDetail?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date
        case orderId = "order_id"
        case orderUniqueId = "order_unique_id"
        case otpStore = "otp_store"
        case product
        case qty
        case status
        case storeName = "store_name"
        case time
        case userDetails = "user_details"
    }
}

// 3
struct UserDetail : Codable {

    let area : String?
    let landmark : String?
    let name : String?
    let number : String?
    let pincode : String?
    let place : String?
}
```

I hope this will help you. Let me know still you have any query.

If you create JSON structure manually than before you should have proper knowledge of making structure. Otherwise it's effect on JSONDecoding. There are lots of website available to make your json codable classes online, one of them is: http://www.jsoncafe.com/

Use this website to create your swift codable classes.

Comment: Let the coding keys generate when possible

Comment: @SagarChauhan it works fine thanks for response. I want to know what was wrong in my code

Comment: `let data : [Data]?` This line will lead to unexpected behaviors. `Data` is a `Foundation` type. Don't use it in your custom structs.

Comment: You are doing some wrong things here. `struct Product: Decodable { var ProductName: String }` & `struct Quantity: Decodable { var qty: String }` which are not required due to those keys contains array of String.

Comment: @Desdenova, Yes you are right. I have changed it. Thanks for noticed.